# Use a photoresistor to read an IR LED from an Itron energy meter

Tags: arduino, sensor, infrared, photoresistor

I want to read my meter at home with an Arduino board. My meter, an [Itron C1S](https://www.itron.com/na/productsAndServices/Pages/CENTRON.aspx), has an IR emitter that pulses once (10ms width) every Wh.

I want to know if it is theoretically possible to use a normal photoresistor to read this values. If yes, how can I specify the photoresistor? If not, what would be the alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if it is theoretically possible to use a normal photoresistor to read this values.

Theoretically, yes.

> If yes, how can I specify the photoresistor?

By choosing one that is sensitive to the IR wavelength range. Which most common ones are not. As seen in this [datasheet](http://ronja.twibright.com/datasheets/cds-resistor-pgm.pdf), photoresistors tend to peak at 650nm, right in the middle of the visible light range.

> If not, what would be the alternative?

So you need something that is sensitive to the IR wavelength range. 900 - 1300nm is typical. **What you want is a IR Phototransistor.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a IR Phototransistor will be. do you think this product will do? http://www.vishay.com/docs/83760/tcrt5000.pdf I need to order to Costa Rica, and dx.com only has this IR Phototransistor.

Comment: @otmezger yep, that should work. Hook it up like this https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/x8xw58/screenshot/540x405/ for a non-inverted logic to your arduino input.