# How to amplify the signal of a TCRT5000 phototransistor

Tags: arduino, amplifier, infrared, phototransistor, power-meter

I'm trying to read the IR signal from my [Itron C1S](https://www.itron.com/na/productsAndServices/Pages/CENTRON.aspx) Power meter. It has an emitter that lights up for 10 ms every Wh of consumption.

This question is based on my prior question: [Use a photoresistor to read an IR LED from an Itron energy meter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112254). I connected the transistor

I hooked it up,but I never get any answer... it seems the Phototransistor is not precise enough... Is there a way to amplify it?

here is my connection (note that Im using the [TCRT5000](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83760/tcrt5000.pdf) phototransistor, not the one on the picture) :

[image]

my code works good and the connection works if I put a reflector in top of the emitter (and if I connect it!).

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Dhcp.h>
#include <Dns.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetClient.h>
#include <Temboo.h>
#include "TembooAccount.h" // Contains Temboo account information

byte ethernetMACAddress[] = ETHERNET_SHIELD_MAC;
EthernetClient client;


// Energy meter ini
int inputPulse= 8;
int StateOld = 0;

int PowerMeterSimPin = 4;
int PowerMeterSimCounter = 0;
int PowerMeterSimCounterOn = 0;
boolean PowerMeterOnStatus = false;


boolean myState = false;

unsigned long diffTime_ms, startTime, p_w;






void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // For debugging, wait until the serial console is connected.
  //delay(4000);
  //while(!Serial);
  /*
  Serial.print("DHCP:");
  if (Ethernet.begin(ethernetMACAddress) == 0) {
    Serial.println("FAIL");
    while(true);
  }
  Serial.println("OK");
  */
  delay(5000);


  pinMode(inputPulse,INPUT);
  pinMode(PowerMeterSimPin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(PowerMeterSimPin, LOW);


  Serial.println("Setup complete.\n");
}

void loop() {


  int state = digitalRead(inputPulse);
  unsigned long now = millis();

  // simulate the power meter: 
  // each 5 sec, consume 1 Wh. 

  /*PowerMeterSimCounter++;

  if (PowerMeterSimCounter >= 5*1000){
    PowerMeterSimCounterOn = 0;
    PowerMeterSimCounter = 0;
    PowerMeterOnStatus = true;
    digitalWrite(PowerMeterSimPin, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Meter is on");

  }


  if (PowerMeterOnStatus){
    PowerMeterSimCounterOn++;
    if(PowerMeterSimCounterOn >= 10){
      PowerMeterSimCounterOn = 0;
      digitalWrite(PowerMeterSimPin, LOW);
      Serial.println("Meter is off");
      PowerMeterOnStatus = false;
    }
  }
  */
  diffTime_ms = now - startTime;

  // detect rising edge of IR detector
  if ((state == true) && (StateOld == false))
  {
    // new start Time
    startTime = now;
    StateOld = true;

    // we know the energy is 1Wh = 3600 Ws
    // calculate the power as p = E/dt
    p_w = 3600UL*1000UL/diffTime_ms;

    Serial.print("Time[ms]; ");
    Serial.println(diffTime_ms);
    Serial.print("Power[W]: ");
    Serial.println(p_w);
    Serial.print("Energy[Wh]: ");
    Serial.println(1);
    if (myState){
      digitalWrite(PowerMeterSimPin, LOW);
      myState = false;
    }else{
      digitalWrite(PowerMeterSimPin, HIGH);
      myState = true;
    }

    /*


      TembooChoreo CreateObjectChoreo(client);

      // Invoke the Temboo client
      CreateObjectChoreo.begin();

      // Set Temboo account credentials
      CreateObjectChoreo.setAccountName(TEMBOO_ACCOUNT);
      CreateObjectChoreo.setAppKeyName(TEMBOO_APP_KEY_NAME);
      CreateObjectChoreo.setAppKey(TEMBOO_APP_KEY);

      // Set profile to use for execution
      CreateObjectChoreo.setProfile("EnergyMeter");

      // Set Choreo inputs
      String ObjectContentsValue = "{\"value_Wh\":1}";
      CreateObjectChoreo.addInput("ObjectContents", ObjectContentsValue);

      // Identify the Choreo to run
      CreateObjectChoreo.setChoreo("/Library/Parse/Objects/CreateObject");

      // Run the Choreo; when results are available, print them to serial
      CreateObjectChoreo.run();

      while(CreateObjectChoreo.available()) {
        char c = CreateObjectChoreo.read();
        Serial.print(c);
      }
      CreateObjectChoreo.close();
    */
    // don't want to read short pulses as 3600*1000/100 = 36 kW


  }
  if ((diffTime_ms>100)&& (state == false))
    {
      StateOld = false;
    }
  delay(1);
}
```

(note that the temboo stuff is commented out)

NOTE: According to the Itron Technical Reference Guide, the Meter has an infra red LED:
[image: Itron Technical Reference Guide - Screenshot]

UPDATE: As recommended by tman, I performed a reading for a long period of the analog value of the meter. Here are the results:
[image]

As you can see, we have some effect of the sun. Ignore that. As you can see, the signal jumps between 1013 and 970 almost all the time (noise) and some times it goes down to around 870. I'm not sure if this is when the LED of the meter is on. It should be 10 ms, and I'm not sure how much time there is between measurements (shouldn't it be around 2 ms?). I measure with the same setup and this code:

```
#include <SD.h>
const int chipSelect = 4;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    return;
  }
}

void loop()
{
  String dataString = "";
   int sensor = analogRead(A0);
    dataString += String(sensor);
  File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (dataFile) {
    dataFile.println(dataString);
    dataFile.close();
  }  
  else {
    // do nothing
  } 
  delay(1);
}
```

Is it proper to use more than 1 phototransistor (connected in parallel) to amplify the amount of light collected?

Comment: Is the Itron emitter IR or is it visible light?

Comment: It should be IR. see my edit, I attached a picture of the technical Reference Guide. Sadly, there is no more technical information about the LED itself.

Comment: I merely glanced through your code, but how about reading the analog value and see what ranges  you're getting for a low state and high state for the LED.

Comment: good point... I'll give it a try.

Comment: @tman I updated the question with my measurements results. sadly, it only produced more questions... tell me pls what you think.

Comment: @otmezger where can I read about the Centron IR LED? Id like to check it out to be sure. My next thought is a filter to remove the noise...since you know the signal your looking for this should not be too bad and could be implemented with software or hardware.

Comment: here is the technical guide: http://www.scribd.com/doc/90311312/1482163-201106090057150 there is no much information about the IR there, tho

Comment: @otmezger is your receiver exposed to other light? Would doing this experiment again with a spray painted straw or something to remove all other light except for the meter be possible? If not then your going to have to do some filtering...share the raw data and I'll see what I can do for a software filter.

Comment: Oh dear... I realised that this is totally hopeless. The meter is in a glass container, and I just realised that infra red light won't pass through glass. so it's useless to try to read a IR LED sitting inside  with anything sitting outside the glass. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I've actually done this before, and found that a single unamplified phototransistor is not sufficient.  I did some measurement of light and dark currents and came up with the circuit shown below to produce a nice clean digital signal (I did not use an ADC).  Note that I happened to simply use parts I already had on hand -- the use of 2N2222 transistors is not critical.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fikXX6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In my particular case, I mounted the IR phototransistor in the cap of a cheap ball point pen, and used a suction cup to temporarily affix it to the top of the meter (you must, of course, be careful not to damage the meter).  One can simply accumulate Wh pulses and compute energy usage, of course, but it's also possible to measure the time between pulses and determine demand (in Watts).

Once that's all assembled, the math can be verified using an incandescent light bulb.  I happened to have a 100W bulb and so with no-one else at home, I noted the demand with the bulb off and then again with it on.  In my case, there was precisely a 100W difference, so it was clear that everything was working as designed.

Comment: Thanks. First think I need to do is to darken the meter. It is placed outside on direct light and this is making too much noise. I'll put a cover over it, and then try your circuit out. thanks.